# importlib.import_module - When re-importing modules are subsequent imports from RAM memory?

Tags: python

I have the following python code which loops continuously to load a module with
`module = importlib.import_module`, and then run a function inside the module.

I want to know if subsequent iterations in the loop will load the module from RAM memory and not from the file system source file or from the compiled pyc file in the file system.

In other words I want iteration of the loop to load from RAM, not to read the file system even for the pyc, because RAM is much faster and there are 200 hundred  files to iterate over..

Thanks..

```
loop_count = True
while loop_count :
    for module_name in folderWithModules:
        module = importlib.import_module(f'folderWithModules.{module_name_without_extension}')

        module.executeFunctionInModule()
```